# Hibernate returning PersistentBag instead of List

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following relationship b.w two entities given below ,when I get OutletProductVariety object from repository ,the price is coming in PersistentBag and not as a List even after using fetchtype Eager.

```
@Entity
public class OutletProductVariety  {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "varietyId")
  Variety variety;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "outletVariety", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<Price> price;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Price {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long Id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="outletVareityId")
  private OutletProductVariety outletVariety;

  private Double price;
}
```

How can I get a List of prices rather then PersistentBag?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic How can i get List of prices rather then  PersistentBag

Comment: Care to mention the JPA provider in use? because this will only happen with one particular JPA provider, so "JPA" is not returning anything; your provider is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at Hibernates `PersistentBag`

> An unordered, unkeyed collection that can contain the same element 
>   multiple times. The Java collections API, curiously, has no
>   Bag.  Most developers seem to use Lists to represent
>   bag semantics,  so Hibernate follows this practice.

```
public class PersistentBag extends AbstractPersistentCollection implements List

protected List bag;
```

It implements `java.util.List;` so it is basically a `List` and wraps your List internally

It is just Hibernates way to represent your List.

Comment: Please note however that PersistentBag violates the contract of `equals`, so that `normalList.equals(persistentBagList) => true` but `persistentBagList.equals(normalList) => false`  https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5409