# How to use Model Mapper in spring security?

Tags: spring-boot, modelmapper, spring-security-rest

I try to replace `BeanUtils.copyProperties` with `ModelMapper.map()`. I get error when try to login with spring security:

```
1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@2a5749f5 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag to java.util.List.

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:380) ~[modelmapper-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:81) ~[modelmapper-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:573) ~[modelmapper-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:406) ~[modelmapper-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.thao.wsapplication.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUser(UserServiceImpl.java:81) ~[main/:na]
    at com.thao.wsapplication.security.AuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:71) ~[main/:na]
```

function `getUser()`

```
@Override
    public UserDto getUser(String email) {
        UserDto returnValue = new UserDto();
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (userEntity == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
        returnValue = new ModelMapper().map(userEntity, UserDto.class);
//      BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEntity, returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }
```

function `successfulAuthentication()`

```
@Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();  

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userName)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret())
                .compact();

        UserService userService = (UserService)SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
        UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(userName);

        res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        res.addHeader("UserID", userDto.getUserId());
    }
```

update my source code: [source code](https://github.com/thaovd1712/UserApplicationWS)

Comment: The user model has something that ModelMapper could not map properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823922/hibernate-returning-persistentbag-instead-of-list

Comment: i updated my source code,  i change to model mapper in another function to use in controller  it works fine, I dont know why use in this function that gets stuck?